# select grouped by column AND aggregated column in one field throws 'nonaggregated etc' error

Tags: mysql, group-by, concatenation

I have a very simple table `invoices`, with a `DATE` column `date`. I want to know how many invoices every year has, easy:

```sql
select year(date) year, count(1) num
from invoices
group by year
```

but I want to throw the results straight into an html `<select>` function that needs a key and label. The key is the generated `year` column, but the label can't be the `num` column, because that's meaningless to the user, so I want to add the year, so a label could be "2023: 83". `concat()` to the rescue, right?

```sql
select year(date) year, concat(year(date), ': ', count(1)) label
from invoices
group by year
```

but NO, mysql doesn't like that, because `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` (which I generally like, because strict is good).

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'invoices.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I understand why it's complaining, but HOW ELSE can I select this? I know the query is technically correct, even according to `only_full_group_by` logic. I can't also group by generated `label`, that makes no sense. I can make a subquery, but c'mon that's silly:

```sql
select year, concat(year, ': ', num) label
from (
  select year(date) year, count(1) num
  from invoices
  group by year
) x
```

I know I can combine this in logic after the query, but I want to throw the mysql results straight into the `<select>` generator function, so mysql has to give me exactly what I want to show the user. Can I just not use `concat()` in an aggregation query? (I don't do that, but this project is old and probably pre-`only_full_group_by`.)

Comment: I tried using `GROUP BY YEAR(date)`, that didn't solve it, either. I think the subquery may be the only solution.

Comment: From MySQL looking point you want to combine the data of different grouping levels in one expression: `year(date)` which is aggregating expression and `count(1)` which is aggregated expression. And subquery/CTE seems to be the only option.

Comment: Why do you want to do this concatenation in sql code? Do it in your application code, when you generate the labels for the dropdown

Comment: @Shadow I could do that, but I said I don't wanna, and I do wanna know if this is possible. This is not about good design, this is about me wanna and maybe mysql canna.